# android room suspend insert success but does not return id

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use room database with suspend keyword.

I can **successfully insert a data** into database. But after that, the **insert method will not return anything**, that means I can't do anything after insertion such as insert another data by the returned id.

here is my sample code:

```
@Dao
interface EventDao {
    ...

    @Insert
    suspend fun insert(event: Event): Long

    ...
}

class EventRepository(...) {
    ...

    suspend fun insertEvent(event: Event, personId: Long) {
        val id = eventDao.insertSync(event)

        // !!! FREEZE - the code below here will never reach !!!

        val attendee = EventAttendee(
            personId = personId,
            eventId = id
        )
        eventAttendeeDao.insert(attendee)
    }

    ...
}

class EventEditingViewModel(...) : ViewModel() {
    ...

    fun addEvent(event: Event) {
        event.userId = userId
        viewModelScope.launch {
            eventRepository.insertEvent(event, friendId)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Actually, if I remove `suspend` keyword, I can get the return id properly. The freezing problem will only happen when I use suspend keyword in front of insertion method in Dao class.

Logcat doesn't show any logs of this, and the app doesn't crash, so I have no idea what happened.

My room version is `2.2.1`. and I've tried `2.2.2` also.

Did I do the wrong way to use suspend function in room database?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into coroutines library then found out that my insert method has been canceled cause by ViewModel deleted.

Because I built a `DialogFragment` and do the insertion after I click the `PositiveButton` of `AlertDialog`, so **the viewModelScope has been clear before the insertion finished**.

I think the solution may be the following ways:

1. use another scope such as `GlobalScope.launch` instead of `viewModelScope.launch`
2. dismiss the dialog after insertion.
3. return the data to another fragment, do the insertion in another page.

In this case, I think the best choice is the first choice. It's easier and would not cause any other lifecycles' problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, the easiest way to make this real-time update is to refresh the activity while you are still in the dialog box.
I added these lines of code AFTER I added the user in the database ( in the OK button of the dialog box):

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(getIntent());
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Hope it helps. It worked for me!